# Where can I get a token for in app billing v3 api on appengine or android?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, go, in-app-billing, google-cloud-endpoints

Reading the documentation it is unclear to me how to get a token from either android or appengine endpoint server? I assume they mean by token a oauth2 access token?

> https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1_1/
>   http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html

I did setup a client id like this

[image: console]

In javascript I can get a access token `gapi.auth.getToken().access_token`. But is it the same token? What scope do I need? Is there a API I need to activate in the console?

On appengine I only know how to get a email from the user.

```
var clientids = []string{WEB_CLIENT_ID, ANDROID_CLIENT_ID_d, ANDROID_CLIENT_ID_r, endpoints.ApiExplorerClientId}
var audiences = []string{WEB_CLIENT_ID}
var google_scopes = []string{"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"}

func (s *Service) Google(r *http.Request, req *NoRequest, resp *User) error {
        c := endpoints.NewContext(r)
        g, err := endpoints.CurrentUser(c, google_scopes, audiences, clientids);
        if err != nil {return err}
        resp.Email=g.String()
        return nil
}
```

Can you provide me more info about the token I must use to verify a purchase (in-app-billing v3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I found it, mist this reference :) https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization